# Error in xml parsing in FLASH

Tags: flash, actionscript, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML in FLASH 
This is my Code

```
   var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.load("Playlist.xml");
myXML.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {    

    var foodName  = myXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.name;
    var foodCount = myXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.count;
    var foodType   = myXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.type;

    trace(foodName);
    trace(foodCount);
    trace(foodType);

    }

}
```

This is Generating this Error

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at Trail_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

& pls suggest some tutorial link related to XML parsing in FLASH

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done AS2, but I believe you are out of scope; try this instead...

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.load("Playlist.xml");
myXML.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success) {    

var foodName  = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.name;
var foodCount = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.count;
var foodType  = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.type;

trace(foodName);
trace(foodCount);
trace(foodType);

}

}
```

... i.e. while you are inside the function, there is no object called myXML, because, within that scope, you have moved from your TimeLine object, directly to the myXML object...

so;

`_level0.myXML` exists

`myXML.myXML` does not exist

I don't have Flash handy to try it out, but I think that's it.